# Application Gateway v2 - Use same SSL cert for multiple Listeners?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to setup an Application Gateway v2 sku.
In doing so, i have two ports i want to listen to: 16000 and 16001.
These are setup as listeners using SSL.
Or at least, i want them to be.

They'll eventually both point to different Backend Pools, that have the same domain ending - i.e. *.sites.contoso.com
So, site1.sites.contoso.com and site2.sites.contoso.com, for example.

They both have the same SSL Cert - one for *.sites.contoso.com

When setting up the App Gateway, i'm given the error:

> ApplicationGatewayDuplicateSslCertificate
>
> Application Gateway 
> cannot have same certificate used across two Ssl Certificate elements.
> Certificate for /site1.sites.contoso.com and
> /site2.sites.contoso.com are same.

How can i remedy such an error? I considered trying to reference the same certificate, rather than supplying it twice, but that does not work.
In addition, we're not able to do site-specific certificates.

Comment: it seems that we got around this by putting the certificates in a key vault and then the App Gateway references the key vault.  It was at previous company so can't verify.  This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs

Comment: Thanks, i tried this earlier today - but no luck. However if you say it worked, i will give it another go in case i've messed something up somewhere. Will report back tomorrow!

Comment: That actually did work - referencing the same certificate, and removing the duplicate with different name. Now i just need to properly figure out where i went wrong with Certs, as i receive ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT when trying to use the Gateway. Thanks!
Post as an answer, and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an ARM Template, the solution is to reference the same certificate in multiple locations, rather than define the certificate in more than one location.

So, if you have a parameter with certificate reference to a Key Vault, re-use that parameter in each place the Certificate should be used.

More information on the topic of using Key Vaut certificates in general can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs

Thanks to [Scott Mildenburger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622056/scott-mildenberger) for the answer.